# load external file from command prompt instead of using from classpath

Tags: java, properties

I am working with maven project and I have a `quartz.properties` file in `/src/main/resources` folder.

Now I can use this property file in two ways from this class as shown below:

```
/**
 * Create a StdSchedulerFactory that has been initialized via
 * <code>{@link #initialize(Properties)}</code>.
 *
 * @see #initialize(Properties)
 */
public StdSchedulerFactory(Properties props) throws SchedulerException {
    initialize(props);
}

/**
 * Create a StdSchedulerFactory that has been initialized via
 * <code>{@link #initialize(String)}</code>.
 *
 * @see #initialize(String)
 */
public StdSchedulerFactory(String fileName) throws SchedulerException {
    initialize(fileName);
}
```

Now I have made an executable jar using `maven-shade-plugin` and I am running in my ubuntu box as `java -jar abc.jar` and it works fine. It uses `quartz.properties` file from classpath automatically.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    try {
        factory.initialize(App.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("quartz.properties"));
        Scheduler scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
    } catch (SchedulerException ex) {
        System.out.println("error= " + ex);
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to make this program more generic by passing `quartz.properties` file from the command prompt while running my above jar file as shown below:

```
java -jar abc.jar quartz.properties
```

If I do like above, then it should use `quartz.properties` file what I am passing and not from classpath but if there is no argument passed then it should use default `quartz.properties` file. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have access to the command-line args in `main`:

```
if(args.length > 0) {
   ...
   factory.initialize(args[0]);
} else {
   ...
   factory.initialize(App.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("quartz.properties"));
}
```

If there is no `initialize` method that takes a `String`, then you can constructor a `FileInputStream` from the argument:

```
factory.initialize(new FileInputStream(new File(args[0])));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.InputStream-).

```
props.load( new FileInputStream("quartz.properties") );
```

*PS. use try-with-resources so you don't leak the stream like I do, above, and add error handling*